# How to remove oil based concrete sealer from garage door?

Tags: concrete, oil-based-paint, sealer

There are four small spots of sealer on an aluminum garage door. I'm looking for something that will remove it without damaging the door surface.

Comment: gasoline would work

Comment: Gas worked great. It almost instantly dissolved the oil the moment it touched it. No damage to the door either. I used a little more gas just to clean the gas can itself.

Comment: Let me make that a answer, so you can reward me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes simple solution works best.

In your case I would recommend to use some gasoline.

There are other solvents, but I found the gasoline works great.

Comment: Gasoline is a crappy choice of napthatic solvent -- they invented safety solvents for a very good reason!

Comment: Gasoline makes a fantastic solvent (as is lighter fluid). It has some unfortunate side effects that should cause one a bit of pause before using it.